# Tensorflow-Keras CNN Image Classifier accuracy is always at 50%

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm learning CNN using keras and tensorflow. I've done all the pre-processing for the images like converting image to an array , resizing and converting it to a grey scale image. After that I've fed the data to the model but the accuracy is always at 50%. Did I do something wrong ?

I've also tried tweaking the random seed , batch size , reducing the data set size , and also played with the optimizer but nothing really helps

```py
count_dog=0
count_cat=0
#Reading cats and converting them from rgb to black and white
print('-------------------------')
for i in range(5000):
    try:
        caturl=r"C:/Users/Gowtam/Downloads/Compressed/PetImages/Cat/"""
        caturl=caturl+str(i)+'.jpg'
        img = cv2.imread(caturl,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(50,50))
        imglist.append(img_to_array(img))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        count_cat+=1


#Reading dogs and converting them frrom rgb to black and white    
for i in range(5000):
    try:
        caturl=r"C:/Users/Gowtam/Downloads/Compressed/PetImages/Dog/"""
        caturl=caturl+str(i)+'.jpg'
        img = cv2.imread(caturl,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(50,50))
        imglist.append(img_to_array(img))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        count_dog+=1

print(count_cat,'',count_dog)    

#now we have RGB to GREYSCALE converted images| lets create labels
print(len(imglist))

labels=[]

for i in range(5000-count_cat):
    labels.append("cat")
for i in range(5000-count_dog):
    labels.append("dog")
#one hot encoding..!
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
labels50=(labelencoder.fit_transform(labels))

#now lets scramble the data(imgs) and labelencoder in same way

shuffimgs=shuffle(imglist,random_state=20)
shufflabels=shuffle(labels50,random_state=20)



#input shape of image (width,height,depth) depth means how many colors or channels that is 1 as b&W

#now lets normalize the shuffeled and resized imgs

fData=tf.keras.utils.normalize(shuffimgs)

#now lets build the model
#fData = fData[0].reshape(28,28,1)


model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50,50,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(fData,labels50,epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the number of epochs, also can you use prebuilt models like VGG16. Lastly here's a tutorial by the creator of keras

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. I've also increased and decreased epochs but still it doesn't change. I've also followed the tutorial but still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: can you send a link of the dataset also try a deeper network with input size at least 150,150

Answer (score 0):

The first advice I give you is that when it is a binary classification it uses the binary crossentropy for loss, because being a Cat Vs Dog you have to classify if it is one or the other then only two classes.
Activation I recommend a sigmoid since you need two values ​​or 0 or 1.
Try it this way.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_directory,
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='binary'
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_directory,
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='binary'
)
```